# Form not returning value to controller action due to ID conflict

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a form with a DropDownListFor. When I select the ID from my drop down list, select a date and click submit, I get error:

> The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'CasinoID' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Index(Int32, System.DateTime, NameSpace.ViewModels.TerminalReceiptPostData)' in 'Namesppace.Controllers.TerminalReceiptsController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.
>   Parameter name: parameters

It worked fine with just a regular Input tag and typing it in manually... however when I added a DropDownListFor this issue arises. Am I setting up the DDL wrong? Any other issues as to why this would happen? Below is some code.

Controller Action:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(int CasinoID, DateTime Date)
    {
         var model = TRBL.GetTransactionTestsData(CasinoID, Date);

        return View(model);
    }
```

View:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "TerminalReceipts", new { id = "submitForm" }))
 {

    <div>
        @*<input type="text" name="CasinoID" placeholder="Enter Casino ID" id="cIdSearch" />*@
        @Html.DropDownListFor(o => o.TerminalReceiptPostData.CasinoIdDDL, Model.TerminalReceiptPostData.CasinoIdDDL, new { id = "CasinoID"})
        <input id="datepicker" class="datepicker-base" name="Date" placeholder="MM/DD/YYY" type="text" />
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm  btn-primary" id="search" onclick="checkField()"> Search Transactions</button>
    </div>

 }
```

***Edit update***

So I was able to change how the structure a bit to now be able to get the CasinoID to be passed properly to the controller action. Below are the changes... however after the action goes to return the model, I get an obj reference not set to instance of the obj err.

Action:

```
      [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(int CasinoID, DateTime Date)
    {

        var id = Int32.Parse(Request.Form["CasinoID"].ToString());

        var model = TRBL.GetTransactionTestsData(id, Date);

        return View(model);
    }
```

Change to DDL:

```
                @Html.DropDownList("CasinoID", Model.TerminalReceiptPostData.CasinoIdDDL, "Select Casino")
```

Answer (score 1):

The `int CasinoID` will be bound by a form field with the name `CasinoID`. I think the @Html.DropDownListFor is not generating the 'name' you want.

You can add name explicitly like

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(o => o.TerminalReceiptPostData.CasinoIdDDL, Model.TerminalReceiptPostData.CasinoIdDDL, new { id = "CasinoID", name="CasinoID"})
```

Or better to create a ViewModel with the fields CasinoID, Date & CId and use `BindProperty` on that ViewModel instance

Comment: Yeah, I am pretty sure that is what is going on. I tried to put it inside of an <Input > and it looked horrible. I will try this and let you know.

Comment: Nope, same error. Made sense though.. thought this would work.

Comment: From the browser can you check what is the values passed in the form POST? (F12->Network tab in Chrome) Is the 'CasinoID' is passed to the server?

Comment: It appears that it is not.

Comment: I was able to get the value for CasinoID to be passed properly with this change to the drop down. ``` @Html.DropDownList("CasinoID", Model.TerminalReceiptPostData.CasinoIdDDL, "Select Casino")``` I can debug and see it go through...however now I get a different error when page re-loads with the results needed ```Object reference not set to instance of the object``` on the line with the drop down list. I also used this in the controller action to take care of the value ``` var id = Int32.Parse(Request.Form["CasinoID"].ToString());``` and am now passing var id into the TRBL() function call.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I figured out what was going on..

I actually have two seperate controller actions named Index. One for post and one for get. Since I am now sending back a model on the POST one, the drop down list was not getting "re-filled" with the drop downs... So i simply took a call from my GET action and added it to the post..

```
        [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(int CasinoID, DateTime Date)
    {

            var id = Int32.Parse(Request.Form["CasinoID"].ToString());

            var model = TRBL.GetTransactionTestsData(id, Date);

            model.TerminalReceiptPostData = TRBL.GetCasinosDDL();

            return View(model);

    }
```

Probably not the best way to do it, but works fine.